# Formal definition of convexity for multivariate function?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $M\in R^{M\times N}$, a function $f: M\rightarrow R$ is called convex on $M$ if

$f\big((1-\lambda)X1+\lambda X2, (1-\lambda)Y1+\lambda Y2\big) \leq (1-\lambda)f(X1,Y1) + \lambda f(X2,Y2)$

For all $(X1,Y1)\in M$ and $(X2,Y2)\in M$ and all $\lambda\in[0,1]$.

Is the above definition correct for multivariate function?

Comment: Did you mean $f: M \times M \to \mathbb{R}$? In any case, think of it as $f((1-\lambda)M_1+\lambda M_2) \le (1-\lambda) f(M_1)+\lambda f(M_2)$. This way the definition is the same regardless of underlying space.

Comment: For example, $F(X,Y) = tr(I-XY)$, where $X$ and $Y$ are coupled together. How to prove $F(X,Y)$ is convex or not?

Comment: Well, just try the scalar version to see that it is not convex (the Hessian is not positive semi-definite).

Comment: But I still want to know what is a formal definition:)

Comment: The formal definition is the same regardless of space. Look at the first comment above. Think of $f(X) = F(X_1,X_2)$ (where $X = (X_1,X_2)$). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Comment: @copper.hat Still not clear. Can you write out the inequality for function $F(X,Y)=tr(I-XY)$. It will make it more clear to me. Many thanks:)

Comment: $f(X) = \operatorname{tr} (I - X_1 X_2)$. $f(\lambda X + (1-\lambda)Y) = \operatorname{tr} (I - (\lambda X_1 + (1-\lambda)Y_1) (\lambda X_2 + (1-\lambda)Y_2))$. Etc, etc.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I was looking for an answer to the same question, and found this: https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/MathTutorial/CVNF.HTM . Hope it helps.